# How to port and debug math functions into shader code?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to learn to apply the techniques to sdf render a landscape from [Painting a Landscape with Maths](https://youtu.be/BFld4EBO2RE?t=240). In the video, Quilez shows this formula:

[image: the formula]

But I seem to be incorrectly implementing it into glsl. I'm very new to
shaders. This is what I have so far:

```c
 #define PI 3.141593

// a_ij = 2 {uv(u+v)} - 1
float uv_to_cooef(in vec2 uv) {
    return 2.0 * fract(uv.x * uv.y * (uv.x + uv.y)) - 1.0;
}

// S(a,b,x) = 3λ^2 - 2λ^3
float smoothstep01(in float x) {
    return smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, x);
}

float terrain(in vec2 p) {
    vec2 ij = floor(p);
    vec2 i = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
    vec2 j = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
    float s = 500.0;
    float a = uv_to_cooef(s * fract(ij / PI));
    float b = uv_to_cooef(s * fract((ij + i) / PI));
    float c = uv_to_cooef(s * fract((ij + j) / PI));
    float d = uv_to_cooef(s * fract((ij + i + j) / PI));
    float s_xi = smoothstep01(p.x - ij.x);
    float s_yj = smoothstep01(p.y - ij.y);
    return a
        + (b - a) * s_xi
        + (c - a) * s_yj;
        + (a - b - c + d) * s_xi * s_yj;
}

// Use raymarching setup in https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdS3DG but change map to:
vec2 map( in vec3 p, int id ) {
    return vec2(p.y - terrain(p.xz), 1.0);
}
```

I get discontinous junk:

[image: nonsense output from shadertoy]

What are some good ways to debug converting math functions to glsl?

Replacing map with a simpler continuous function produces nice results:

```c
vec2 map( in vec3 p, int id ) {
    float d2 = p.y + sin(p.x / 3.0) * cos(p.y / 7.0);
    return vec2(d2,2.0);
}
```

[image: rolling hills]

So I think that means my function isn't continuous, but **how to debug that?** Break it into 2d functions and graph it on desmos?

The completed [sdf scene is on shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4ttSWf), but I want to *understand* how to get from math to that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was an extra semicolon and glsl didn't complain about the pointless statement on the next line.

```
    return a
        + (b - a) * s_xi
        + (c - a) * s_yj; // bad semicolon
        + (a - b - c + d) * s_xi * s_yj;
```

---

The steps I took to try to debug:

- Visualize the function in another format. [I ported the function to desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hmx9qlasiu) and it was discontinuous.
- [I fixed my desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3r2mfowiu1) (the definition of `a(i,j)` was wrong), but couldn't see how the fixed version was different from my glsl code. My next step was going to be to reduce the function to a simpler continuous one in desmos and then apply the same changes to my glsl code.
- Instead, I noodled around with other code and noticed the semicolon by accident. So luck?